# Remove a dict in a nested dict with ansible

Tags: ansible

I block on manipuling data with ansible / jinja2 / python filter.

I have this yaml structure which is an ansible inventory in yaml

```
all:
  children:
    admin_administration:
      hosts:
        admin_administration1:
          server_ip: 127.0.0.1
    int:
      children:
        int_administration:
        int_console:
        int_swarmanager:
        int_swarmworker:
          children:
            int_swarmvip:
            int_swarminfra:
            int_swarmload:
            int_scw_swarmload:
    int_swarmvip:
      hosts:
        int_swarmvip1:
          server_hostname: swarmvip-001
          server_ip: 127.0.0.1
```

and I have this list of dict:

```
remove_groups:
  - name:
      int_swarmworker:
        children:
          int_swarmvip:
```

I loop on it so the task gets group.name dict on each iteration

```
- name: Remove group from inventory file
  include_tasks: remove_group.yml
  loop: "{{ remove_groups }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: group
```

In the section:

```
        int_swarmworker:
          children:
            int_swarmvip:
            int_swarminfra:
            int_swarmload:
            int_scw_swarmload:
```

Only the int_swarmvip must be removed but if there is no more subobject after removing int_swarmvip below int_swarmworker, the group int_swarmworker must be removed too.

Also this section must be removed:

```
    int_swarmvip:
      hosts:
        int_swarmvip1:
          server_hostname: swarmvip-001
          server_ip: 127.0.0.1
```

So the new yaml ansible inventory should be:

```
all:
  children:
    admin_administration:
      hosts:
        admin_administration1:
          server_ip: 127.0.0.1
    int:
      children:
        int_administration:
        int_console:
        int_swarmanager:
        int_swarmworker:
          children:
            int_swarminfra:
            int_swarmload:
            int_scw_swarmload:
```

I did the add_host with ansible dict combine and I try it to remove a dict --> fail

Also try a custom plugin fillter -> fail

jinja2 code -> fail

I debug too much but I'm sure the solution is easy ...

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
The goal is to manage automatically my static ansible inventory that is pushed to a github repo and sync with AWX

I have already a playbook that remove / add a list of hosts but the code handle only the primary group and not a subgroup like:

```
int_swarmworker:
  int_swarmvip:
    toto:
```

Comment: Could you describe the goal? Do you want to remove the hosts/groups? If so, why? Or do you want to edit a dict and just use the inventory structure as an example?